Not able to get AutoLogon working on Windows 11 22H2
I'm having an issue with enabling autologon feature for one of our kiosk machines. We have many other computers where this is working and this is the only one we've run into issues with. We usually use the SysInternal AutoLogon64 tool and we have also tried setting the correct Registry keys at:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\
AutoAdminLogon = 1
DefaultDomainName set
DefaultUserName set
DefaultPassword set

The odd part is, when we restart the computer, it does not login and sits at the login screen with the username above the username and password field:

This is a domain account attempting to login to a domain joined computer. I have tried the steps provided by this MS article with no luck.

If the local account is linked to a Microsoft Account. You need to make sure you are using the local account's username not the username of the Microsoft Account.  I can confirm that I am able to configure Windows 11 VM to automatically log into a local account on a VM which is linked MS Account for every version of Windows 11 (22H2 through 24H2)

@Ramhound may I ask what method you used? We are using the domain user name and specifying the domain with the sysinternals tool. Even specified the domain in the registry as mentioned. We have a lot of computers in our environment using the same method and they do not have any issues.. Not sure what could be causing this.

The method I have always used. I run lusrmgr.msc, select the option to NOT prompt for a password, and when prompted to save the username and password I enter the username of the local account and the password.

@Ramhound The issue is, this is not a local account. It's a domain account signing into a  domain joined computer. I've followed steps listed in MS own documentation but it still does not work: Microsoft Learn

Your question does not include that critical information.  I assume when you assign the username you are also specifying the domain.

DefaultDomainName set

Is Sysinternal autologon not working? (don't mix Sysinternal Autologon and Registry). I've used domain username and Sysinternal autologon and that works.. if there is an issue - at restart it will say something about it (bad username or password is the most common one). Also if this is to be a Kiosk - Windows 11 has a built-in Kiosk mode - just search for Kiosk and it will come up. Note: This requires a local account.
